Cannot find module 'prisma/generated/client' or its corresponding type declarations
я папку prisma/schema.prisma перенес в src и эта ошибка выскакивает
  "prisma": {
    "schema": "src/prisma/schema.prisma"
  },

import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PrismaClient } from "prisma/generated/client";

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}

